# How do I place a marker on my current location using OSM?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm pretty new to Javascript and OSM. I was wondering how to retrieve coordinates from map.locate(). My current code looks like this:

```js
function getLocation(){
 map.locate({setView: true, enableHighAccuracy: true})
 .on('location found', function(e){
  var marker = new L.marker(e.latlng);
  marker.addTo(map);
 });
```

When I run this code, it gets my current location but the marker won't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo: event name is [`"locationfound"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-locationfound) (no whitespace)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/93/